# mat-paginator - change color of next and previous buttons - Angular 15 Material

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

How can I change the next and previous buttons on the mat-paginator in Angular 15.

```
<mat-paginator
    id="paginator"
    #paginator
    [length]="totalPosts"
    [pageSize]="10"
    (page)="handlePageChange($event)"
    [hidePageSize]="true"
  >
  </mat-paginator>
```

I've tried the following

```
::ng-deep .mat-paginator .mat-icon-button
{
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

or

```
.mat-paginator-navigation-next,
.mat-paginator-navigation-previous {
    color: red;
}
```

or

```
::ng-deep .mat-paginator-navigation-next,
::ng-deep .mat-paginator-navigation-previous {
  color: red !important;
}`
```

How can I change the next and previous buttons? I appreciate any help.

Comment: there is a `color` property on the mat-paginator have you try setting it ? According to the documentation it should change the color of the controls in the paginator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dealing with SVG icon to change it is color you should use fill property instead of background

**Try this:**

```
::ng-deep .mat-mdc-paginator-navigation-next .mat-mdc-paginator-icon{
  fill: red !important;
}
```

**[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vpixre?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpaginator-overview-example.ts)**